# iMacros formatting random numbers as currency, does not affect the same field each time

Tags: imacros

This has me stumped. Running a basic data input macro taking data from a CSV file. I have tried formatting the numbers as both general and numbers in excel. It seems to affect random fields - for example, on one run it will affect boxes 1, 3, and 7, and on run 2 it will affect boxes 2, 5, and 8.

For example, this is a line of code:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:Zip CONTENT={{!COL1}}
```

In half of the boxes, the entry will be formatted as 58123, and the other half $58,123.00.

I believe this may be a bug related to the implementation of the firefox plugin I am using, as I just ran the code on the same form twice in a row. Same data, same page, no reloads or anything. It had the same issue both times, however the boxes it affected were different. Boxes that were formatted correctly the first time were formatted incorrectly the second, and vice versa. It may also be caused by the plugin being thrown off by boxes that format numbers as currency automatically, as the macro will just "paste" the value in the box without triggering the formatting script, so I would get results like this:

cost: 150
cost: $150
cost: 150

when all of them should read $150 and there is a JS currency formatting function applied to the box. The end result being that numbers that should be formatted as currency are not, and numbers that should not be formatted as currency are.

@chivracq
I slowed timing down to one event every 2s and it did not improve the issue. I am using iMacros 8.9.7 on firefox 47. Windows 10. iMacros FF v10 breaks support for several commands that I need, and Chrome has it's own particular issues with the sites I have to use. Unfortunately finance tends to be picky - surprised we got off of IE6, really. The first version of iMacros I purchased was v8 if I remember correctly, and most of the basic ideas/code were written back then and updated as needed. With iMacros being discontinued now I don't see a point in fixing the issues newer versions have - if I can't get this working I suppose I will have to learn a different automation framework.

My apologies for missing the wiki.
A snippet from my CSV would look like this:

```
12345678,1407 W Random St,Arlington,22205,800000,800000,10/10/2022,10/20/2022
```

I could snag some of their code from element inspector perhaps?

Comment: Could you mention your FCI like explained in the [Tag Wiki](/tags/imacros/info)...? // Could you include a mini Data Sample from your '.csv', (opened from 'Notepad' and not 'Excel')...? // Can post the URL...? // Related to some JS Validation/Formatting from the Page/Site, I would think. // You mention "Firefox" => probably using `v10.1.0 for FF` (FCI not mentioned), could try using `v10.1.1 for CR` on 'Chrome' + try using the `EVENT` Mode (not supported by `v10.x for FF`) which might be "better" at triggering the JS Validation than the `TAG` Mode...

Comment: Could be a Timing Issue, that iMacros is "too quick" and the Page/Site doesn't have the time to apply the Data Validation/Formatting for some Input Fields, => could try adding some mini `WAIT` Statement (=0.1) after each `TAG` (or `EVENT`) Statement, , ... or some general `!PLAYBACKDELAY` Command (=0.1) for that Section...

Comment: @chivracq I updated the original question with some details. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @chivracq Update: more weird bugs - if the `TAG` `INPUT:TEXT` command is used with `CONTENT=01/01/2021` (etc) it works 99% of the time. However, if it is `CONTENT={{!COL11}}` containing the exact same data from the CSV file, it doesn't work. I have tried making sure that the data was formatted as dd/mm/yyyy but it didn't have an effect. I have also been messing around with Selenium (ui.vision) which is able to fill these forms with a type command consistently, but has it's own host of problems and limitations so I am still trying to get imacros to work right now.

Comment: OK, v8.9.7 for FF is "perfect" actually, best Version, (works until FF56, "recommended" = FF v55.0.3), => try using the `EVENT` Mode, like I had already suggested... // Would need a `PROMPT _{{!COL11}}_` in your Script to make sure the Data is formatted as `01/01/2021` (and not as `1/1/2021` for example)... // Further, not much I can do with just 1 Line of your Script, no HTML Structure of the Page and no way to test myself... Your Case/Thread might be more suited for the iMacros Forum maybe, rather than 'SO' which is more for some "easy" Qt => straightforward Answer..., not for Debugging...